# Get the count if specific column is NULL in table rows [Telerik]

Tags: sql-server, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I just created telerik report using telerik standalone report designer tool.

This is the structure of that report

[image]

this is the SQL query I used

```
    SELECT
    [tbl_HEI_student].[Gender],
    DATEDIFF(hour,[tbl_HEI_student].[Date_of_Birth],GETDATE())/8766 AS Age,

FROM (([tbl_HEI_student]
 FULL OUTER JOIN [tbl_hec_CIVIL_Status]
 ON [tbl_HEI_student].[ID] = [tbl_hec_CIVIL_Status].[ID])

WHERE ([tbl_HEI_student].[Gender]='Male' or [tbl_HEI_student].[Gender]='Female') AND ([tbl_hec_CIVIL_Status].[Status]='Married')
```

I want to count the rows if [tbl_HEI_student].[Date_of_Birth] is NULL(Age is NULL)

Which is get that count to **Age unknown** section

how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

The below query should do,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tbl_HEI_student] WHERE [Date_of_Birth] IS NULL
```

If you want the answer as part of the above query itself, The above can be given as sub query or you will have to define a function to get the count.